# Android how to set ActionBar in just one Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am new to Android and I'm facing this problem. 
I got MainActivity with items list, when one of them is clicked then the DetailActivity starts.

I disabled ActionBar with

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">`

so the MainActivity no longer have actionBar. But I want this ActionBar in the DetailActivity ( i need the basic one, with the left arrow to get back to MainActivity ), so I created another style

`<style name="DetailTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">`

and used it in activity_detail.xml like this 
`android:theme="@style/DetailTheme"`

But it seems this is not the right way, because there is no ActionBar in that Activity .

I'm currently not sure if DetailActivity will be the only one with ActionBar, so I would like to know how to activate it on just this one Activity.
What is the right solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but maybe try assigning it to the activity in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DetailTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> used it in activity_detail.xml like this `android:theme="@style/DetailTheme"`

My best guess is that you mean you added the `android:theme` attribute to the root view tag in your layout file. Maybe something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/DetailTheme"
    ...
    />
```

This doesn't actually apply the theme to your *Activity*, it only applies the theme to your Activity's "content view". Content views don't have action bars, so those attributes of the theme will be ignored.

To apply a theme to an Activity, you have to specify it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:theme="@style/DetailTheme"/>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for explaining. Adding theme to manifest did the trick.